# Is it possible that multiple instances run a single SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I created a worker environment with multiple instances on aws elastic beanstalk. A *cron.yaml* is defined in the worker environment which sends tasks to a queue. My question is whether several instances can perform the same task in the queue.

I have already set the *visibiltyTimeout* to 0 seconds so that the task is visible for every instance. however, the task will not be deleted from the queue if it completes successfully.
the task is only deleted when the *maximum message retention period* of one minute expires.

Any ideas?

edit:
to clarify my issue: I want to send emails via worker environments. Since the number of recipients is so large, I want to distribute the task over several instances.

Comment: You should not use SQS for that purpose but SNS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

Comment: Can you clarify your issue? This is not how SQS should be used.

Comment: @Marcin no need to delete imho, I agree with this comment and the one under your answer, SQS is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @luk2302 Its fine, please feel free to make answer, as I got confused know what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @luk2302 Could you explain in more detail how sns solves my problem? The solution with HTTP endpoints only applies to web server environments, or do I get it wrong?

Comment: No idea what you want to actually do but relying on retry mechanisms of SQS to have the message deliver to multiple receivers is just a misuse of the entire service. If a message should be picked up by multiple consumers use SNS. No idea how that would work in your situation or why different services would even need the same message but a single SQS message for multiple services is definitely the wrong solution.

Comment: Maybe 1000 messages instead of 1 is better and then all the environment can regularly pick one of the messages, work on the batch of data corresponding to that message and then delete it and move on the next message.

Comment: @luk2302 I thought of that too. In my case I would then set a cron job for every minute. But suppose I have 7 instances and the task only takes 4 minutes. Then not all instances would carry out the tasks, because after 4 minutes the first instance is ready for use again. However, my goal is for all instances to execute the task at the same time, so that the emails can be sent faster.